# Understanding the radius of convergence under function composition

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

I am currently working myself into polynomial approximation of functions where you get very useful bounds by viewing them as functions over complex arguments. While doing this I noticed something peculiar I have not been able to wrap my mind around:

Consider the function $$f(z) =\log\exp(z).$$ From my naive point of view, this is equal to $z$ and hence holomorphic on the whole complex plane. But if I look at the function composition I would get that the radius of convergence of the Taylor expansion is only $\pi$ as $z=\pm i\pi$ gives $\log -1$, the argument lies on the negative real axis where we get problems with the logarithm.

How can I resolve this apparent contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no contradiction. $\log$ is a multivalued function.  $z$ is one of the branches of $\log \exp(z)$ and is holomorphic on the whole complex plane, but it is not the only possibility.  If you use the principal branch of $\log$, which has a branch cut on the negative real axis, then you get a branch of $\log \exp(z)$ that has branch cuts wherever $\exp(z)$ is on the negative real axis ($\text{Im}(z) = i n \pi$ for odd integers $n$).

Comment: I get this point, but I do not see how we get to the branch $z$ from the function composition -- don't I always have to select one of the branches of $\log$ to make the function composition work? Or can I choose a branch of $\log$ depending on $z$?

Comment: Yes, the branch of $\log$ must depend on $z$.  You certainly can't just select a particular branch of $\log$, because $\exp$ is not a one-to-one function.  For example, $\exp(0) = \exp(2\pi i) = 1$, so you need to use $\log(1) = 0$ when the $1$ comes from $\exp(0)$, but $\log(1) = 2 \pi i$ when the $1$ comes from $\exp(2\pi i)$.

Comment: Excellent, I did not know this was "allowed", but then it makes a lot of sense. Thanks!